# Reading complex/related data using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to read (using EF) City and Country information like CityID, CityName, CountryID, CountryName from the tables City and Country, which has appropriate FK relation.

For this, I can use

1. `from x in db.Cities.Include("Country") select x` - This results in complex query which tries to read all unwanted columns
2. `from x in db.Cities join y in db.Countries on x.CountryID equals y.CountryID select new CityDTO{ x.CityID, x.CityName, y.CountryID, y.CountryName}` - This results in creating lots of DTO classes and transformations.
3. `from x in db.CityView select x` - this results in creating many views and whenever I want to get additional column, I need to update the edmx.
4. Create additional property called `CountryName` in City class

and use

```
from x in db.Cities select x
foreach (var city in x)
  city.CountryName = (from y  in db.Countries where ...)
```

*** This is because EF is not allowing me to create City object inside the query otherwise I would have used `from x in db.Cities join y in db.Countries select new City{x.CityID, x.CountryID, x.CityName, y.CountryName}`

What is the best way to go in this case (with less entities and performing query)?

Comment: have you tried doing this using `DataClassesDataContext` and bypassing EF which will still allow you to do proper linq query's based on a single table or 3 tables for example along with joins..
if not also are you aware that `List<T>` has a List<T>.foreach that you could probably perform on your your linq query provided that you do `select x.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from x in db.Cities.Include("Country") 
select new { x.CityID, x.CityName, x.Country.CountryID, x.Country.CountryName }
```

This selects just the specified fields into an anon type, allowing you to select only cols you care about

To use an existing entity you can use a similar syntax, eg.

```
from x in db.Cities.Include("Country") 
select new City { 
         CityID = x.CityID, 
         CityName = x.CityName, 
         Country = new Country{ 
                       CountryID = x.Country.CountryID, 
                       CountryName = x.Country.CountryName 
                   } 
         }
```

If you look at the generated SQL for either of these expressions you will see that its only selecting the mentioned columns.

Do be aware however that the entity returned from both of these queries is not tracked, so you cant use it directly to perform an update.

Comment: The only problem with anon types is that they are difficult to manage (type casting / accessing attributes) across the method calls (when used like I/O parameters). Ideally in enterprise applications, these objects has to flow across UI layer, Business Layer and DAL.

Comment: You could create a new type for this subset DTO, and select into that instead? Otherwise the options are either select into a partially empty (and not tracked) EF entity, or use an anon type.

Comment: Just wondering how to use the partially empty and not tracked EF entity.

Comment: @KrishnaSarma see edits, is this what you were after?